# HelloSign iframe display in PHP custom page

Tags: php, iframe, hellosign-api

I need to integrate the HelloSign API in my PHP code.
I followed this way but iframe is not coming.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.hellosign.com/public/js/hellosign-embedded.LATEST.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    HelloSign.init("0005fc6cf93ce7ce6116778265107d5a");
HelloSign.open({
    url: "https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?signature_id=78caf2a1d01cd39cea2bc1cbb340dac3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a",
    uxVersion: 2,
    allowCancel: true,
    debug: true,
    skipDomainVerification: true,
    height: 640
});
</script>
```

Console error:

```
{url: "https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?sign…c3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a", uxVersion: 2, allowCancel: true, debug: true, skipDomainVerification: true, …}
allowCancel:true
debug:true
height:640
skipDomainVerification:true
url:"https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?signature_id=78caf2a1d01cd39cea2bc1cbb340dac3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a"
uxVersion:2
__proto__:Object
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: {url: "https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?sign…c3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a", uxVersion: 2, allowCancel: true, debug: true, skipDomainVerification: true, …}
allowCancel
:
true
debug
:
true
height
:
640
skipDomainVerification
:
true
url
:
"https://app.hellosign.com/editor/embeddedSign?signature_id=78caf2a1d01cd39cea2bc1cbb340dac3&token=b6b8e7deaf8f0b95c029dca049356d4a2cf9710a"
uxVersion
:
2
__proto__
:
Object
This is the error in the console

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you're calling the HelloSign.open() function in order to bring up the iFrame. Please let us know if you run into any other errors!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the sign_url that you are using is from our example listed on the Embedded Signing Walkthrough. Each sign_url will need to be dynamically generated.

Please review the following documentation for more information, [Embedded Signing Walkthrough](https://app.hellosign.com/api/embeddedSigningWalkthrough).

Please let me know if you have any additional questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - thanks for stopping by and supporting your API here. You mean created using create_embedded or create_embedded_with_template? (I appreciate you have well written documentation, but the usual StackOverflow convention is to include a bit more information in the answer rather than just link to something external. But the point about reusing the example token is probably enough here - thanks!)